# Find error record file while processing too many files in same bucket in apache beam java sdk

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io, apache-beam-internals

I have 20 files (csv files) in the same bucket. I am able to read all the file in one go and load on to bigquery. But when there is some data type mismatches, im able to get that row into `invalidDataTag` where as i am unable to find the file name that has the error record.

inputFilePattern is `gs://bucket-name/*` this picks up all the files that are present under the bucket. and reading the files as below

`PCollection<String> sourceData = pipeline.apply(Constants.READ_CSV_STAGE_NAME, TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFilePattern()));`

Is there a way where i can find the file name that has the error row in it ?

Comment: As far as I know only using FileIO you can get the metadata of the file, which then you can access when you open a file in a ParDo.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to add a column to the BigQuery table that indicates which file the record came from.

Comment: Thanks for your response and could you please help us with sample code the approach ?